# Terminal Login Screen Language between SSH and Telnet

Tags: centos, login, language

on the login screen of a CentOS 7, when changing password is enforced with an ssh terminal I have two different languages:

```
login as: user1
user1@192.168.0.20's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Mon Aug 19 14:24:21 2019 from srvfw01.dummy.lan
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Ändern Passwort für Benutzer user1.
Ändern des Passworts für user1.
(aktuelles) UNIX-Passwort:
```

In the telnet session the login looks like this:

```
srverp01 login: user1
Password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Changing password for user1.
(current) UNIX password:
```

Both environments show:

```
>env |grep LANG
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

How can I change the whole message block to German language for telnet and ssh login?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Can you update your question with the output of `env | grep LANG` in both environments?  Also, do you really need `telnet`?  Allowing remote access with plaintext passwords is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Probably you should also check LC_ALL variable as well. Otherwise you might need to regenerate locales

Comment: the user's (any user's) environment after they've logged in is irrelevant here.  It's the system's default locale that matters - that's what sshd and login and telnetd and xdm/gdm/lightdm etc will use **before** the user logs in.